How to get Time Zone ID in Blazor Server App
In My Blazor server app I can successfully get the current time zone via JS Interop like so:
    window.timeZone = () => {
    var timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
    return timezone;
};

This will give me e.g. Europe/Berlin
In my C# code I need the Time Zone ID to convert a given UTC time to this current Time Zone.
Manually I can do this like so:
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(file.CreatedDateTime.Value, "W. Europe Standard Time");

Where "W.Europe Standard Time" is the Time Zone id. Now my question is how can I dynamically find out this Time Zone ID, when the Time Zone (e.g. Europe/Berlin) is given?
Thank you in advance for any help.

moment.js should have the Ids for you.

You could use TimeZoneInfo, "Europe/Berlin" is the "Id",  "W. Europe Standard Time" is the "StandardName".
var enCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = enCulture;
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = enCulture;

TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/Berlin");
Console.WriteLine(timeZone.StandardName);



Tried this but the StandardName is in german for me: it's saying "Mitteleuropäische Zeit" as StandardName

@bbWebDev You could try set the cultureinfo to "en-US" before using TimeZone as the modified answer.
